# Is this statement true in the banach space?

Tags: real-analysis

Is this statement true? Why?
For any $f$ in $L_{1}(0,1) $ such that $f>0$, a.e, in $[0,1]$ we have $\int f(u)\ge\int uf(u)$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(u) > 0$ a.e. and $u \in (0,1)$ implies that $f(u) \geq uf(u)$ a.e, so also $\int f(u)\,du \geq \int uf(u)\,du$.